# httpd.conf setting to allow scripts to connect to the network

Tags: firewall, httpd, soap

This is connected with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985115/nusoap-fsockopen-error-couldnt-open-socket-connection-to-server-error-13

I think I am unable to have my php application get access to the network. The error reported is in the above link.

What the solution proposed in http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/red-hat-fedora-linux/46840-fsockopen-error-13-permission-denied.html is:

> The firewall is enabled on my server:
>   policy type is targeted, enforcing
>   current is checked and HTTPD scripts
>   to connect to the network were not
>   allowed.
>
> Where: Desktop > System Settings >
>   Security Level > SELinux > httpd >
>   HTTPD scripts to connect to the
>   network was unchecked.  I checked it
>   and it is working now.

How can I change httpd.conf to do the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem partially.

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/apache

```
httpd scripts by default are not allowed to connect out to the network.
This would prevent a hacker from breaking into you httpd  server
and attacking other machines.  If you need scripts to be able to
connect you can set the httpd_can_network_connect boolean on.

setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

I ran this command and my script runs properly now, but I'm not sure if this setting will be retained if I restart the server / apache. Does anyone know what I have to do make this a 'permanent' setting?

Comment: I tested this by rebooting the server - the setting is retained